# How to prevent an image being removed from UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

So basically what I'm doing is rendering a bunch of images for a list. These are rendered in a asynchronous queue system and then set through a closure. Now when the app enters the background or the image view is not on display for a while the image contained in it gets deallocated. The sample code looks something like this:

```swift
class SomeView: UIView {

    let someObject: SomeObject
    let imageView = UIImageView()

    init(someObject: SomeObject) {

        self.someObject = someObject

        super.init(frame: .zero)
        // setting constrains and stuff

        self.loadImage()
    }

    func loadImage() {
        let request = ImageQueueRequest(for: someObject, closure: { (image) in
            self.imageView.image = image
        }
        ImageQueue.execute(request)
    }

}
```

Now the deallocation itself is not a huge problem, the images are cached for performance reasons anyways, but I cannot see any way to get notified when this kind of deallocation happens so I can request the image from the cache again.

Is there any type of way to observe deallocation or see when the view enters the visible frame to load the image again? Or is this even the problem I'm facing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is actually deallocated? As far as I know this should only happen when there is no reference left to it.

Comment: You should be able to fix it by calling `tableView.reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear`, but it seems strange to me this is happening at all. I've never experienced this issue.

Comment: @Adrian No I am not entirely sure, but I cannot think of any other reason why it would stop being displayed, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AdamPro13 yes this would a a viable option for some scenarios, but I sometimes render a bigger version of the image into a scroll view, where the image also disappears from the image view when out of frame for too long

Comment: After the image disappears, are you sure the imageView still has the same frame you expect it to have?

Comment: @AdamPro13 yes, I'm sure, the frame does not change at any point